# Azure Web Api 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

When trying to hit the Web API endpoint via postman and javascript from a visual studio web project I get the error

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I do not understand why credentials are required as the ASP.NET MVC Web API application deployed to Azure has no authentication configured.

[image]

below is screen shots of the network tab in the chrome developer toolkit
[image]
[image]

Additionally  below is a screen shot of postmon  (with the URL removed for privacy).

[image]

Comment: any update on this

Answer (score -1):

You site need to be supplied with `windowsAuthentication`.So, add the following code in your `web.config` and try again.

```
<authentication mode="windows">
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.netwrix.com/kb/1486).